# How to get GPS details of images taken with flutter camera plugin

Tags: plugins, camera, flutter

Using the flutter camera plugin ,am taking pictures for which I need to know the EXIF information. Any suggestions

Comment: What have you tried so far? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: I have got the solution by using imagepicker for taking the pics. Those images include the EXIF info

Comment: @SKR It seems that GPS metadata is not being collected when I use image_picker with native_exif on my iOS device. Are there any solutions you have?